# How do I get a sound file's total time in Java?

Tags: java, file, audio

How do I get a sound file's total time in Java?

--UPDATE

Looks like this code does de work:
long audioFileLength = audioFile.length();

```
    recordedTimeInSec = audioFileLength / (frameSize * frameRate);
```

I know how to get the file length, but I'm not finding how to get the sound file's frame rate and frame size... Any idea or link?

-- UPDATE

One more working code (using @mdma's hints):

```
    AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
    AudioFormat format = audioInputStream.getFormat();
    long audioFileLength = file.length();
    int frameSize = format.getFrameSize();
    float frameRate = format.getFrameRate();
    float durationInSeconds = (audioFileLength / (frameSize * frameRate));
```

Comment: Which jar file are you using for this?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Given a `File` you can write

```
File file = ...;
AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
AudioFormat format = audioInputStream.getFormat();
long frames = audioInputStream.getFrameLength();
double durationInSeconds = (frames+0.0) / format.getFrameRate();
```

Comment: I don't what's wrong, but with a file of 18 seconds your code produce a result 149120 while the new code I posted in the question produce 18.64275 (the correct size in seconds). Anyway, I wouldn't have done this without the hints, thanks!

Comment: @mdma : can you please help me in my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29115389/how-can-i-modify-the-pitch-of-an-audio-file-at-different-time-instants-in-java

Comment: com.sun.media.sound.RIFFInvalidDataException: Chunk size too big, https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8132782

Answer (score 0):

I have used JAudiotagger library. It is super easy to use and supports almost all audio formats.

Add dependency in pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.jthink</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaudiotagger</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Below code is to extract audio file metadata

```
try {
    AudioFile audioMetadata = AudioFileIO.read(file);
    System.out.println("Audio Metadata {}",audioMetadata.displayStructureAsPlainText());
    System.out.println(audioMetadata.getAudioHeader().getTrackLength());
    System.out.println(audioMetadata.getAudioHeader().getBitRate());
} catch (CannotReadException | IOException | TagException | ReadOnlyFileException
        | InvalidAudioFrameException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Error while getting metadata for audio file. Error " +  e.getLocalizedMessage());
}
```

Reference - https://jthink.net/jaudiotagger/index.jsp

Answer (score -1):

This is a easy way:

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
long duration = 0;

try {
    fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(pathToFile);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    duration = Objects.requireNonNull(fileInputStream).getChannel().size() / 128;
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(duration)
```