# Audio file duration without AudioSystem class in Java (GAE)?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, audio

There is already a more general answer (Java) at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009908/how-do-i-get-a-sound-files-total-time-in-java but unfortunately

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem is a restricted class. Please see the Google App Engine developer's guide for more details.
```

`AudioSystem` is not on the [Google App Engine JRE Class White List](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist?hl=hr&csw=1) and therefore can't be used. Any other approach?

I have (already uploaded) audio files sitting on Google Cloud Storage (GCS) and I can load them into `ByteArrayInputStream` but somehow I need to convert them into `AudioInputStream` to get the audio file duration (and save the duration in the database).

Answer (score 0):

A support ticket for Audio Manipulation API along the lines of the Images service is currently in WontFix status: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1947, so it is unlikely that there will be support for this in near future. Issue was reopened again: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=6442

The solution at this point would be to work with external Audio APIs that are available as a Service. Maybe a list from ProgrammableWeb on [Audio APIs](http://blog.programmableweb.com/2013/05/14/51-audio-apis-soundcloud-shoutcast-radio-and-evoca/) could help.