# How to get duration of audio file?

Tags: java, audio, javasound

I want to get duration (total time) of audio file in seconds. Audio file can be of any format I.E. (.mp3, .wav, .wma etc.).

```
 try {
    File file = new File("C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Temp/" + 
        "01 - Ab Tere Bin Jee Lenge Hum-(MyMp3Singer.com).mp3");
    AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
    AudioFormat format = audioInputStream.getFormat();
    long frames = audioInputStream.getFrameLength();
    double durationInSeconds = (frames + 0.0) / format.getFrameRate();
    System.out.println("duration in seconds"+durationInSeconds);
    AudioFileFormat audioFileFormat = AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(file);
    Map<String, Object> properties = audioFileFormat.properties();
    System.out.println("properties"+properties.size()+"empy::"+properties.isEmpty());
    for(String key: properties.keySet()){
        System.out.println(key  +" :: "+ properties.get(key).toString());
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exception:::::" + e.getMessage());
}
```

I have tried to do this using above code but it is giving:

```
Exception:::::could not get audio input stream from input file
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009908/how-do-i-get-a-sound-files-total-time-in-java

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing the MP3 codecs. You might want to try [Tritonus: Open Source Java Sound](http://www.tritonus.org/).

Also check the related thread: [MP3 playback using Java Sound and Sun MP3 plugin](http://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/mp3-playback-using-java-sound-and-sun-mp3-plugin.149533/)

Comment: is it library if yes please give sample program to get audio file duration

Comment: @programminglover:- The program which you have written is correct. You  just need to add some jar files like `jl.jar mp3spi.jar and tritonus_share.jar to my classpath` to your classpath

Comment: See also the **Service Provider Interface** & **MP3 decoding support** sections of the [Java Sound Wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info).  The JMF had an MP3 decoder included.  Include `mp3plugin.jar` (name?) on the run-time class-path and you should be set to go.  I used it for a Java Sound based MP3 jukebox.

Answer (score 0):

The duration of an audio file is often provided as a property of `AudioFileFormat`. From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/sound/sampled/AudioFileFormat.html):

> The following table lists some common properties that should be used in implementations:
>
> #### Audio File Format Properties
>
> ```
> +-------------+------------+-----------------------------------------------+
> |Property key | Value type | Description                                   | 
> |-------------|------------|-----------------------------------------------|
> | "duration"  | Long       | playback duration of the file in microseconds |
> | "author"    | String     | name of the author of this file               |
> | "title"     | String     | title of this file                            |
> | "copyright" | String     | copyright message                             |
> | "date"      | Date       | date of the recording or release              |
> | "comment"   | String     | an arbitrary text                             |
> +-------------+------------+-----------------------------------------------+
> ```

Note the *should*, meaning they are optional.

Also note, `duration` is given in *microseconds*, not milliseconds!

So to get the duration of an audio file in Java, you could call:

```
final String DURATION = "duration";
Long duration = (Long)audioFileFormat.properties().get(DURATION);

// and because duration is optional, use a fallback
// for uncompressed formats like AIFF and WAVE
if (duration == null
    && audioFileFormat.getFormat().getEncoding() == PCM_SIGNED
    // make sure we actually have a frame length
    && audioFileFormat.getFrameLength() != NOT_SPECIFIED
    // make sure we actually have a frame rate
    && audioFileFormat.getFormat().getFrameRate() != NOT_SPECIFIED
    // check if this is WAVE or AIFF, other uncompressed formats may work as well
    && (audioFileFormat.getType() == WAVE || audioFileFormat.getType() == AIFF)) {

    duration = (long) (audioFileFormat.getFrameLength() / audioFileFormat.getFormat().getFrameRate() * 1000L * 1000L);
}
```

This snippet would get you the duration in microseconds either from the `duration` property or from frame length and frame rate. **The latter is only useful for uncompressed formats like WAVE or AIFF**.

Since mp3 is not supported by current JVMs out of the box, you need to install an mp3 codec. This comes in the form of a service provider implementing the [Service Provider Interface (SPI)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/SPI-intro.html). A pure Java implementation of the SPI for mp3 is the Tritonus library. For usage with Maven, see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17737483/942774). Note that the library has apparently been abandoned a long time ago. A more current package, using [CoreAudio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_Audio) for Mac is [CASampledSP](https://www.tagtraum.com/casampledsp/). Another library, based on [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org) and written for Mac and Windows, is [FFSampledSP](https://www.tagtraum.com/ffsampledsp/) (full disclosure: I'm the author of both these libraries).

Another, slightly more unconventional way to get the duration, is to use JavaFX, as it supports mp3 out of the box:

```
import java.io.File;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.util.Duration;

final Media media = new Media(new File("somefile.mp3").toURI().toString());
final Duration duration = media.duration();
```