# Java getAudioInputStream trying to read audio file, getting javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException,

Tags: java, audio, wav, sample

I am trying to load a wav file in my java program, using the code I found here:
[How do I get a sound file's total time in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009908/how-do-i-get-a-sound-files-total-time-in-java)

However, at line 14:

```
AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
```

I get the error

> "Unhandled exceptions: javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException, java.io.IOException"

This is my code:

```
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("").toAbsolutePath();
        File file = new File(path+"/sample/loop1.wav");
        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
        AudioFormat format = audioInputStream.getFormat();
        long audioFileLength = file.length();
        int frameSize = format.getFrameSize();
        float frameRate = format.getFrameRate();
        float durationInSeconds = (audioFileLength / (frameSize * frameRate));
    }

}
```

I want to make a method to select the starting playing point in the audio file (eg: start playing the file at 30 sec). That's why I wan't to retrieve the duration of my file.

When I do `System.out.println(file);` it prints the correct path of my file.
However, since I am getting an error message, I'm obviously not doing something right.

I have already tried to find a solution online but I didn't find anything, so I posted here.

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream` throws these exceptions.

These are [checked exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6115896/2670892) so you must either use a `try ... catch` block to catch the exception or add a `throws` clause to the method declaration.

A basic `try ... catch` would be:

```
try
 {
   Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("").toAbsolutePath();
   File file = new File(path + "/sample/loop1.wav");

   AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);

   AudioFormat format = audioInputStream.getFormat();

   long audioFileLength = file.length();
   int frameSize = format.getFrameSize();
   float frameRate = format.getFrameRate();
   float durationInSeconds = (audioFileLength / (frameSize * frameRate));
 }
catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException ex)
 {
   ex.printStackTrace();
 }
```